# Laravel4: Use different model depending on config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I extended my Laravel4 Project with another Project Model. Now I have two Models (like Model1 and Model2). My goal is to set a custom config var, telling the installation which Project model to use.

Is there a way to set this in the config and then use Project1 as Project in my Controllers?
If I call `$p = new Project;` I want it to be an instance of either Project1 or Project2, depending on the configuration.

I hope you understand my question, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kind of achieve this by using the IoC container.

First, instead of using `new Project`, use `App::make('Project')` - that won't change anything yet, but will allow you to now 'redefine' what 'Project' points to.

So the next step is, in your startup script (or a service provider if you're using service providers) code similar to the following:

```
if (Config::get('model', 'Project') != 'Project') {
    App::alias('Project', Config::get('model', 'Project'));
}
```

This line will bind whatever classname you set in 'model' in the main config to be what the code retrieves when you use `App::make('Project')`. The reason for the if is just so we don't end up aliasing `Project` to `Project`. Feel free to test it without, but it may create an infinite loop/recursion in the IoC.

The code may not be perfect as it's untested, but at the very least it should give you a path to explore.

---

### Points to note

- You may find App::bind('project', Config::get('model')); works better, especially if you start using the IoC container's automatic injection
- As mentioned above, the `if` surrounding the magic line may not be required. The IoC container may well be clever enough to not keep following an alias to itself.

#### A note on static access

I mentioned before to change all instances of `new Project` to `App::make('Project')`, but I didn't mention how to change your code when using something like `$projects = Project::all();`. Well you can still do a similar thing, but you just have to get an instance: `App::make('Project')->all();`.

When you start going down this route, you find that you're having to `App::make('Project')` more and more. When this is the case, using Laravel's automatic dependency injection will help a lot. To do this, you typehint the class in your controller's constructor:

```
class ProjectController extends \Controller
{
    protected $project;

    public function __construct(Project $project)
    {
        $this->project = $project;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $projects = $this->projects->whereVisible(1)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();
        return View::make('projects.index', compact('projects'));
    }
}
```

This automatic injection happens in a few classes. I don't know the full list, but certainly controllers, event listeners, view creators and view composers. If you have a class of your own you wish to take advantage of the automatic injection, you can `App::make()` it and it too will get its dependencies injected automatically.

Comment: Thank you. How would the code `Project::orderBy(..)->...` look now?

Comment: You would use the automatic dependency injection to inject `Project` into your controller.  You would end up with something similar to $this->project->orderBy(..)->..`.  Check out the Automatic Resolution section here... http://laravel.com/docs/ioc

Comment: Exactly - in an ideal world you wouldn't have any App::make('Project') calls (and therefore, before my code no `new Project` calls) but instead rely on Laravel's very nice automatic dependency injection. To do this you simply tell Laravel that you will be needing a `Project` instance in the controller's (or event listener, or view composer/creator) constructor, and it'll give you one. As @user3158900 said, you then use it as a class property. Don't worry about the fact that it's now an instance as opposed to static, the static-looking code like `Project::all()` is just Laravel sugar anyway.

Comment: Also, going down this route starts taking you towards the repository pattern, where you pretty much do exactly this, but also have a layer of abstraction between the controller and the model. In general the repository pattern is seen as good code design, so you're kind of on to a winner!

Comment: @Strernd I have updated the answer to go into detail a little more on the static access and automatic dependency injection.

Comment: thank you for your effort @alexrussel I'm always feeling dumb dealing with topics like DI and IoC, I guess I have to get used to it. I'll try it out!

Comment: No problem @Strernd, I think your situation is quite rare, but using the IoC certainly isn't. When you start thinking about it as more of a key=>value store (with extra magic for resolving classes) it gets quite simple. That said, there's still plenty to be confused about with Laravel's IoC container as there are about 10 methods all for slightly different things, most of which can be done 3 ways with varying method parameters! (Example: bind a shared instance - `App::bind(..., ..., true)`, `App::instance()`, `App::singleton()`, `App::bindShared()`, and all do slightly different things.)

Comment: @Sterrnd I very highly suggest checking out Laravel: From Apprentice To Artisan.  It's a book written by the creator of Laravel.  It's pretty short, but extremely helpful in understanding DI and IoC in regards to Laravel with some terrific examples.  It really helped me make a lot of sense out of all this.